# change linux process priority

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, process

I ran a jar file in Linux and it is running from last 3 days.

How can I change priority of that process? Will it speedup my
application processing?

Comment: 3 days? Are you sure it still processing something?

Comment: I like to use the term **niceness** in the context of **nice/renice** tools. This is because there are also other aspects which affect how much CPU a process can get. For example see scheduling attributes and **chrt**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I change priority of that process?

renice priority [-p] pid

> Useful priorities are: 20 (the
>   affected processes will run only when
>   nothing else in the system wants to),
>   0 (the ``base'' scheduling priority),
>   anything negative (to make things go
>   very fast)

Example: `renice -5 -p 123`, 123 is process PID, -5 is priority

> Will it speedup my application processing?

No, if load average less number of CPU core.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There is no other process running on my computer. Will it make a big diff. to change priority? I checked my process priority and it is 0. What does it mean?

Comment: The default priority will share equally among running processes.  Nicing the process is usually used to allow other processes to run faster, slowing the niced process if other processes are running.  Negative priorities require root privileges, and can halt all other processes.  Avoid them for anything CPU intensive.

Comment: The key to remember is that the number is how nice the process is to others. a big number means it is very nice. a negative number means it is not nice at all and won't let the other processes play.

Answer (score 1):

You can change priority with `renice` command. It will speed up processing only if there are other applications actively consuming CPU time.

Answer (score 0):

By default process priority in Linux is 0. Process priority can have any number between -20 to 19. Process priority can be set by using nice and modified using renice. -20 is the highest priority process and 19 is the lowest priority.

Here you're having a process already running and you want to change its priority. So you can enter the following command

```
renice -5 pid
```

where pid is the process id of the process whose priority you want to modify. To increase the priority of a process i.e. to set the priority value to a negative value, you need to be root user or use sudo.

Hope that helps.